# C# storing generics state

Tags: c#, generics, fsm

```
public abstract class State<T>
{
    public virtual Enter(T item)
    {
            // an empty method
    }
}

public class ChaseState : State<FieldPlayer>
{
    public override Enter(Player pl)
    {
        // ...
        pl.Fsm.CurrentState = ChaseState.Instance;
        //...
    }
}

public class TendGoal : State<Goalkeeper>
{
   public override Enter(Goalkeeper gk)
   {
       // ...implementation
       gk.Fsm.CurrentState = TendGoal.Instance;
       // ...implementation
   }
}

public class DefendState : State<Team>
{
    public override Enter(Team team)
    {
        // ....    
        team.Fsm.CurrentState = DefendState.Instance;
        //.....
    }
}
```

"Goalkeeper" and "FieldPlayer" inherit from an abstract class "Player", while "Team" inherits from another class.

```
public class FSM
{
    public /*some type*/ owner;         // PROBLEM 1
                                        // OWNER CAN BE TEAM, GOALKEEPEEPER
                                        // OR FIELD PLAYER
    public /*some type*/ globalState;
    public /*some type*/ currentState;
    public /*some type*/ previousState;
    public void Update()
    {
        if (globalState != null)
        {
            globalState.Execute(owner);  // PROBLEM 2
                                         // IF GLOBAL STATE'S TYPE
                                         // IS AN OBJECT, CANT CALL EXECUTE
                                         // OBJECTS TYPE WILL BE KNOWN ONLY
                                         // DURING RUNTIME
        }
     }
}
```

Each object of type "Goalkeeper", "FieldPlayer" and "Team" will have a State Machine instance. The problem is.. generics cant be properties.

What should I do ?

Comment: Should I change the whole design, if yes, how ?

Comment: It doesn't look like your abstract class needs to be generic. You can make the abstract class just a normal object and implement that abstract class in each of the objects. Then, you can just add State type properties to your FSM class. After reading it some more, you will actually need to make State a normal Interface since there is no base work you are doing in that abstract class.

Comment: @CalebKeith How will I override virtual methods with different parameters ?

Comment: Enter(Goalkeeper gk) and Enter(Team team) override the virtual method Enter(T item) from the State class.

Comment: You need to make your Player, GoalKeeper, Team, etc.. classes all have a common interface too.

You could also take a generic object as a parameter and check it's type before doing work. I mean, this is kind of hard to give an exact answer since I don't have full knowledge of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make State an ordinary interface, not generic, and have its Enter method take another interface that your teams, goalkeeprs, players, etc all implement (it can even just be empty), it ought to work.

```
public interface IOwner {}

public interface IState
{
    void Enter(IOwner item);
}
public class ChaseState : IState
{
    public void Enter(IOwner pl)
    {
        // ...
        //...
    }
}
public class Player :IOwner { }
public class Something {
    IOwner owner = new Team();
    IState globalState = new ChaseState();
    IState currentState = new DefendState();

    public void Update()
    {
        if (globalState != null)
        {
            globalState.Enter(owner); 
        }
        else if (currentState != null)
        {
            currentState.Enter(owner);
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading your code some more, an Abstract Class is unnecessary here. You should convert State to an interface, ex: IState and remove the generic signature from it. Then your properties in your FSM object can all be public IState globalState, etc..